# getting smallest of coordinates that differ by N or more in Python

Tags: python, database, numpy, scipy

suppose I have a list of coordinates:

```
data = [
    [(10, 20), (100, 120), (0, 5), (50, 60)],
    [(13, 20), (300, 400), (100, 120), (51, 62)]
]
```

and I want to take all tuples that either appear in each list in data, or any tuple that differs from *all tuples in lists other than its own* by 3 or less.  How can I do this efficiently in Python?

For the above example, the results should be:

```
[[(100, 120), # since it occurs in both lists
  (10, 20), (13, 20), # since they differ by only 3 
  (50, 60), (51, 60)]]
```

(0, 5) and (300, 400) would not be included, since they don't appear in both lists and are not different from elements in lists other than their own by 3 or less.

how can this be computed? thanks.

Comment: What function do you have in mind that takes the difference of two tuples and returns an int?

Comment: suppose it's the sum of the difference between start coordinates and difference between end coordinates

Comment: Seems to me that "differs from all tuples in lists other than its own by 3 or less" means that (10, 20) cannot appear in the result, since it is more than 3 off from, say (300, 400).  Did you mean to say that you should include an item where a match to within three can be found in another list?  In all other lists??

Comment: let me clarify: if it's different from at least one tuple (by 3 or less) in all lists other than its own.

Comment: "Difference between coordinates" is meaningless.  Do you mean "Euclidean distance between coordinates"?

Comment: So, each tuple is a point, and you mean "find all points which are no more than 3 units distant from at least one point in all lists".  (The "appears in each list of data" is redundant, since a point is zero-distance distant from itself anyway.)

Comment: Are you asking how to do this, or how to do this efficiently?  Doing this in a naive (slow) way is trivial--just iterate over each point and compare against all other points.

Comment: to answer your first question, therefore you can have a look at python's set functions, eg. set(listA) & set (listB) will give you there intersection! http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html

Comment: @user248237: Can I ask what's the use case of this question? I may be able to point out alternative routes.

Comment: Thought: Div each list by 3 temporarily, so that (10,20) becomes (3,6) [div, not divide]. Then, hash:

push(@{$hash{3,6}},[1,10,20]); # point 10, 20 appears in list 1

Now, for each hash key, search for candidates that are 1 away from the key (Eg, $hash{2,6}, $hash{3,7}, etc). This uses 8 lookups per element and may be more efficient.

The above is an outline, not guarenteed to work or even compile.

Comment: @barrycarter: Great idea. But does that work for true 2d distances, or is it only comparing differences element-wise?

Answer (score 1):

A naive implementation of this will be slow: O(n^2), testing for each node against each other node.  Use a tree to speed it up.

This implementation uses a simple quadtree to make searching more efficient.  This doesn't make any attempt to balance the tree, so a badly-ordered list of points could make it very inefficient.  For a lot of uses, simply shuffling the list is likely to make it good enough; just be sure not to pass it a lot of items sorted by coordinate, since that'll reduce it to a linked list.

The optimization here is simple: if we're looking for items within a Euclidean distance of 3 units of some point, and we know that all items in a subtree are at least 3 units to the right, there's no way any points in that area could possibly be less than 3 units away.

This code is public domain.  Try not to turn it in as homework.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math

def euclidean_distance(pos1, pos2):
    x = math.pow(pos1[0] - pos2[0], 2)
    y = math.pow(pos1[1] - pos2[1], 2)
    return math.sqrt(x + y)

class QuadTreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        """
        Create a QuadTreeNode at the specified position.  pos must be an (x, y) tuple.
        Children are classified by quadrant. 
        """
        # Children of this node are ordered TL, TR, BL, BL (origin top-left).
        self.children = [None, None, None, None]
        self.pos = pos

    def classify_node(self, pos):
        """
        Return which entry in children can contain pos.  If pos is equal to this
        node, return None.

        >>> node = QuadTreeNode((10, 20))
        >>> node.classify_node((10, 20)) == None
        True
        >>> node.classify_node((2, 2))
        0
        >>> node.classify_node((50, 2))
        1
        >>> node.classify_node((2, 50))
        2
        >>> node.classify_node((50, 50))
        3

        X boundary condition:
        >>> node.classify_node((10, 2))
        0
        >>> node.classify_node((10, 50))
        2

        Y boundary conditoin:
        >>> node.classify_node((2, 20))
        0
        >>> node.classify_node((50, 20))
        1
        """
        if pos == self.pos:
            return None
        if pos[0] <= self.pos[0]:       # Left
            if pos[1] <= self.pos[1]:   # Top-left
                return 0
            else:                       # Bottom-left
                return 2
        else:                           # Right
            if pos[1] <= self.pos[1]:   # Top-right
                return 1
            else:                       # Bottom-right
                return 3
        assert False, "not reached"

    def add_node(self, node):
        """
        Add a specified point under this node.
        """
        type = self.classify_node(node.pos)
        if type is None:
            # node is equal to self, so this is a duplicate node.  Ignore it.
            return

        if self.children[type] is None:
            self.children[type] = node
        else:
            # We already have a node there; recurse and add it to the child.
            self.children[type].add_node(node)

    @staticmethod
    def CreateQuadTree(data):
        """
        Create a quad tree from the specified list of points.
        """
        root = QuadTreeNode(data[0])
        for val in data[1:]:
            node = QuadTreeNode(val)
            root.add_node(node)

        return root

    def distance_from_pos(self, pos):
        return euclidean_distance(self.pos, pos)

    def __str__(self): return str(self.pos)

    def find_point_within_range(self, pos, distance):
        """
        If a point exists within the specified Euclidean distance of the specified
        point, return it.  Otherwise, return None.
        """
        if self.distance_from_pos(pos) <= distance:
            return self

        for axis in range(0, 4):
            if self.children[axis] is None:
                # We don't have a node on this axis.
                continue

            # If moving forward on this axis would permanently put us out of range of
            # the point, short circuit the search on that axis.
            if axis in (0, 2): # axis moves left on X
                if self.pos[0] < pos[0] - distance:
                    continue
            if axis in (1, 3): # axis moves right on X
                if self.pos[0] > pos[0] + distance:
                    continue
            if axis in (0, 1): # axis moves up on Y
                if self.pos[1] < pos[1] - distance:
                    continue
            if axis in (2, 3): # axis moves down on Y
                if self.pos[1] > pos[1] + distance:
                    continue
            node = self.children[axis].find_point_within_range(pos, distance)
            if node is not None:
                return node
        return None

    @staticmethod
    def find_point_in_range_for_all_trees(point, trees, distance):
        """
        If all QuadTreeNodes in trees contain a a point within the specified distance
        of point, return True,  Otherwise, return False.
        """
        for tree in trees:
            if tree.find_point_within_range(point, distance) is None:
                return False
        return True

def test_naive(data, distance):
    def find_point_in_list(iter, point):
        for i in iter:
            if euclidean_distance(i, point) <= distance:
                return True
        return False

    def find_point_in_all_lists(point):
        for d in data:
            if not find_point_in_list(d, point):
                return False
        return True

    results = []
    for d in data:
        for point in d:
            if find_point_in_all_lists(point):
                results.append(point)
    return set(results)

def test_tree(data, distance):
    trees = [QuadTreeNode.CreateQuadTree(d) for d in data]
    results = []
    for d in data:
        for point in d:
            if QuadTreeNode.find_point_in_range_for_all_trees(point, trees, 3):
                results.append(point)
    return set(results)

def test():
    sample_data = [
            [(10, 20), (100, 120), (0, 5), (50, 60)],
            [(13, 20), (300, 400), (100, 120), (51, 62)]
    ]
    result1 = test_naive(sample_data, 3)
    result2 = test_tree(sample_data, 3)
    print result1
    assert result1 == result2

    # Loosely validate the tree algorithm against a lot of sample data, and compare
    # performance while we're at it:
    def random_data():
        import random
        return [(random.randint(0,1000), random.randint(0,1000)) for d in range(0,500)]
    data = [random_data() for x in range(0,10)]

    print "Searching (naive)..."
    result1 = test_naive(data, 3)

    print "Searching (tree)..."
    result2 = test_tree(data, 3)
    assert result1 == result2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()

    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would get you started. Any improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Appears in all lists is trivial - simply take the intersection of all elements in the list.

```
>>> data = [
...     [(10, 20), (100, 120), (0, 5), (50, 60)],
...     [(13, 20), (300, 400), (100, 120), (51, 62)]
... ]
>>> dataset = [set(d) for d in data]
>>> dataset[0].intersection(*dataset[1:])
set([(100, 120)])
```

"Different by at 3 or less" with tuples other than the ones in the same list appears to me a graph/2d space problem. There's no simple algorithm for this, without a polynomial algorithm, and if your dataset is not very big, you could just iterate through them and group close points that are not in the same list.

Answer (score 0):

@barrycarter's intuition is interesting: to reduce the number of comparisons (where by "comparing" two points we mean checking if their distance is `<= 3`), "virtually slice" the 2D plane into suitable "cells", so that each point need only be compared with ones in adjacent "cells". This could really help (wrt a brute force solution where each point needs to be compared with basically all others) if your data set is large.

Here's a Python implementation of the idea (since barry's code sketch appears to be Perl or something), aiming for clarity rather than for speed...:

```
import collections
import math


def cellof(point):
    x, y = point
    return x//3, y//3

def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.hypot(p1[0]-p2[0], p1[1]-p2[1])

def process(data):
    cells = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, points in enumerate(data):
        for p in points:
            cx, cy = cellof(p)
            cells[cx, cy].append((i, p))
    res = set()
    for c, alist in cells.items():
        for i, p in alist:
                for cx in range(c[0]-1, c[0]+2):
                    for cy in range(c[1]-1, c[1]+2):
                        otherc = cells[cx, cy]
                        for otheri, otherp in otherc:
                            if i == otheri: continue
                            dst = distance(p, otherp)
                            if dst <= 3: res.add(p)
    return sorted(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':  # just an example

    data = [
        [(10, 20), (100, 120), (0, 5), (50, 60)],
        [(13, 20), (300, 400), (100, 120), (51, 62)]
    ]
    print process(data)
```

When run as a script, this produces the output

```
[(10, 20), (13, 20), (50, 60), (51, 62), (100, 120)]
```

Of course, to determine whether this is worthwhile, or the simpler brute-force approach is indeed better, the only viable approach is for you to run benchmarks of both solutions on **realistic** data -- the kinds of data sets your program will actually need to deal with in real life.  Depending on how many lists you have, how many points on each, how closely spaced, performance can vary a lot, and it's better to measure than to guess!-)